# Difference of Lower and Upper Riemann Sums

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

You have a bounded function $h$ that maps the closed interval $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. When it comes to its Riemann integrals, it is known that that $\int _{0}^{\overline1}h = 1$ and $\int _{\underline0}^{1}h = 0$.

Is there always a partition such that $U(\alpha,h) - L(\alpha,h) = 1$? Either way, prove also that there is at least one partition $\alpha$ of $[0,1]$ such that $1 \leq U(\alpha,h) - L(\alpha,h) < 1 + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

While I was able to get the left side of the required inequality, I can't figure out the other half and the next part of the problem. I know that if the function had been Riemann integrable, we would have a partition $\alpha$ such that $\mid U(\alpha,h) - L(\alpha, h) \mid < \epsilon$ but can we use this fact in this problem? If not, how would we go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $U(\alpha,h)-L(\alpha,h)<1+\epsilon$ for some $\alpha$ we look at the upper and lower sums, for which we know $inf_{\beta} U(\beta,h)=1$ and $sup_\beta L(\beta,h)=0$.

Since we know the supremum and infimum we can rephrase that to: 
There exists $\alpha$ such that $ U(\alpha,h)\leq\epsilon/2+1$ and $\alpha'$ such that $L(\alpha',h)\leq\epsilon/2 $.

Now we can take a refinement $\alpha''$ that includes both partitions, so both estimates hold. A counterexample could be

For that partition $\alpha''$ we get $U(\alpha'',h)-L(\alpha'',h)\leq 1+\epsilon$.

For the second part we know that the supremum and infimum doesn't need to exist equivalently such partition doesn't need to exist.

An counter example is $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $x\mapsto 2x$ if x is irrational and $x \mapsto 0$ else. Here $U(\alpha,h)\neq 1$ for all partitions $\alpha$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Just one small clarification, we know that $L(\alpha',h)\leq\epsilon/2 $ because $-\epsilon/2 \leq L(\alpha',h)\leq sup_\beta L(\beta,h)=0$, right?

Comment: Exactly! And the same idea can be used on the infimum of the upper sum.

Comment: Thanks. I also just saw that you added the counter-example. While I get that the difference between the upper and lower sums will never equal 1, how do we know that in this case, $\int _{0}^{\overline1}h = 1$? I already get why $\int _{\underline0}^{1}h = 0$ and that for any partition $\alpha$, $L(\alpha, h) = 0$.

Comment: The upper sum will behave just the same way it behaves on $f(x)=2x$, where the upper sum is, visually speaking, always a bit over our graph and never cover it exactly.

Comment: And the upper sum converges like in $\int_0^1 2x dx$.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Basically, $g(x)=2x$ has an upper Riemann integral of $1$ (since $\int_{0}^{1}2xdx=1$) and the function you have defined will always be slightly less than it. So $sup[U(\beta,f)] = 1$ even if there is no partition $\alpha$ such that $U(\alpha,f) = 1$. But while I get the intuition, is there any way to "rigorously" show that it is true (i.e. show the convergence)?

Comment: Rigorously would be to explicitly calculate it. For any partition $\alpha=(0=t_0 ,t_1,...,t_n =1)$, we get $U(\alpha,f)=\sum_{i=1}^n 2 \cdot t_i \cdot (t_i-t_{i-1})> 1$.

Comment: Alright, thank you again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107217/discussion-between-throwawayaccountforrandomstuff-and-timmathstf).

Answer (score 1):

For each $\epsilon>0$, there exist partitions $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ such that
\begin{align*}
U(\alpha_1, h) & \leq \overline{\int_0^1} h + \epsilon/2, \\
L(\alpha, h) & \geq \underline{\int_0^1} h - \epsilon/2 .
\end{align*}
Considering $\alpha = \alpha_1 \land \alpha_2$ gets our inequality.

Now for equality, i.e. a function $h$ and a partition $\alpha$ for which $U(\alpha, h) = 1, L(\alpha, h) = 0$, you can consider the case where $h$ is the indicator on $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e.
$$h(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & x \not \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
for any partition $\alpha$.

However, equality won’t always be possible. Consider now $h’$ which is the same as the above $h$, but it takes the value of $2$ at $x = 1/2$ instead of $1$. Then every $U(\alpha, h’)$ will be equal to $1$ plus the length of the interval in $\alpha$ which contains $1/2$.

Comment: The inequality proof is perfect. Thanks. However, while your example does prove that it is possible for the difference between the upper and lower sums to be equal to 1, I'm not sure it shows that it always the case. Maybe I am misinterpreting though.

Comment: @throwawayAccountForRandomStuff My apologies, I missed that part. The answer should be no, but I’ll add it to the answer tomorrow.

Comment: No worries; thanks though.

Comment: @throwawayAccountForRandomStuff Check now.

Comment: Sorry but I don't completely get it. How does it show that the Upper Riemann sum will be more than 1?

Comment: @throwawayAccountForRandomStuff If $U(\alpha, h’) = \sum_{i = 1}^n (t_i - t_{i - 1}) \sup_{[ t_{i - 1}, t_i ]} h’$, then all those intervals which don’t contain $1/2$ will contribute their own length to the sum, and their lengths add up to $1$, but the intervals containing $1/2$ will contribute *double* their lengths, pushing the total sum over $1$, albeit only by the lengths of those intervals. I say “their” because $1/2$ could potentially sit on the endpoint of two intervals.